# jQuery UI Accordion restrict clicking to certain part of header

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Say that I had a rather complex formatted header for a jQuery UI accordion, lets say something like this:

```
<div id="list-accordion">
  <div class="list-accordion-header">
    <span class="list-thumb-container">
      <a href="someplace_thumb.jpg" title="some title" class="group1">
        <img src="somplace_large.jpg" />
      </a>
    </span>
    <div class="list-basic-details">
      The basic explanation comes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-extra-detail">
    All the rest of the information in the panel of the accordion
  </div>
</div>
```

Would it then be possible to apply the accordion header look and feel to the entire header, so to the div with class .list-accordion-header, but make it only work, in other words only open the .list-extra-detail div below it, when one certain element within the header is clicked? In this case, the div with .list-basic-details. Mind you, I would like to keep the link around the image alive for its own purpose, without triggering the accordion.

Currently I have the accordion working in this way, with the whole of the header active, which I would like to change:

```
$("#list-accordion").accordion(
    {
        icons: false ,
        autoHeight : false ,
        active: false ,
        header: '.list-accordion-header' ,
        collapsible: true
    }
);
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this issue by thinking in a different pattern. I still use the whole of the header to click and open the pane, except that I block that click if it is on a certain element inside the header. In this case, the thumb. So, when somebody clicks the thumb, the accordion stays closed.

For a full description of this different approach to my problem, have a look here:
[jQuery ColorBox plugin within an UI accordion header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112511/jquery-colorbox-pluging-within-an-ui-accordion-header)